# Running Javascript in cdt Chrome DevTools Java Client (com.github.kklisura.cdt)

Tags: javascript, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to run javascript before rendering in cdt?

page.**addScriptToEvaluateOnLoad**("(function() { alert("testing")})()")
page.**addScriptToEvaluateOnLoad** executed on page load and not after the dom is completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to make use of **com.github.kklisura.cdt.protocol.commands.Runtime**
In the below example method, I will remove the sticky, fixed content from a webpage before converting it into a pdf

```
private void convertToPdf(Long masterSourceId, String url, String outputFilePath, Double screenshotLoadTime) {
    ExecutorService mainExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try (ChromeLauncher launcher = new ChromeLauncher()) {
        Callable<Boolean> pdfTask = () -> {
            Map<String, Object> additionalChromeArguments = new HashMap<>();
            additionalChromeArguments.put("no-sandbox", true);
            ChromeArguments chromeArguments = ChromeArguments.builder().noFirstRun().noDefaultBrowserCheck()
                    .disableBackgroundNetworking().disableBackgroundTimerThrottling()
                    .disableClientSidePhishingDetection().disableDefaultApps().disableExtensions()
                    .disableHangMonitor().disablePopupBlocking().disablePromptOnRepost().disableSync()
                    .disableTranslate().metricsRecordingOnly().safebrowsingDisableAutoUpdate().headless(true)
                    .disableGpu(true).hideScrollbars(true).muteAudio(true)
                    .additionalArguments(additionalChromeArguments).build();
            additionalChromeArguments.put("no-sandbox", true);
            ChromeService chromeService = launcher.launch(chromeArguments);
            ChromeTab tab = chromeService.createTab();
            ChromeDevToolsService devToolsService = chromeService.createDevToolsService(tab);
            devToolsService.getEmulation().setScriptExecutionDisabled(false);
            devToolsService.getEmulation().setDocumentCookieDisabled(true);
            Page page = devToolsService.getPage();
            page.enable();
            page.navigate(url);
            page.onLoadEventFired(loadEventFired -> {

                /*
                 * This below script will make sure that any floating, sticky cookie popups in
                 * the web Page will not cover the content when the pdf is being taken from the
                 * HTML THe script will return the dom elements after javascript has modified
                 * the values
                 */

                Runtime runtime = devToolsService.getRuntime();
                runtime.evaluate(
                        "(function(){x=document.querySelectorAll('*');for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){elementStyle=getComputedStyle(x[i]);if(elementStyle.position=='fixed'||elementStyle.position=='sticky'){x[i].remove();}}}())");
                runtime.evaluate(
                        "(function() {l = document.getElementsByTagName(\"a\"); for (var i =0; i<l.length; i++) {l[i].href = \"\"; } }())");
                dump(masterSourceId, outputFilePath, page.printToPDF(false, false, true, null, 11.7, 16.5, null,
                        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, true, null).getData());
                devToolsService.close();
            });
            devToolsService.waitUntilClosed();
            chromeService.closeTab(tab);
            return true;
        };
        Future<Boolean> exeFuture = mainExecutor.submit(pdfTask);
        exeFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(masterSourceId + " : ERROR OCCURED IN HTML TO PDF CHROME CONVERTER : " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        mainExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```